# $t > 0 $ is the least common multiple of $a, b$ (not both $0$) iff $a, b \mid t$ and $a, b \mid c \to t \mid c$

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

My attempt:

Suppose $[a, b] = t =$ lcm of $a, b.$

By definition of lcm $a, b \mid t$.

If $a, b \mid t$  and $a, b \mid c$, then $|t| \le |c|$ since $t$ is the smallest such integer. So, $t \mid c$.

Assume $a, b \mid t$. It is in the definition of lcm, so it passes.

Also, assume $a, b \mid c \to t \mid c$. Then $t \mid c \to |t| \le |c|$  and since $t > 0, t \le c$.

Please, check and see.

Comment: You wrote "iff $a, b \mid t$ and $a, b \mid c \to t \mid c$".  I think this was to be parsed as "$\text{iff }\Big( (a, b \mid t\text{ and }a, b \mid c) \to t \mid c\Big)$", not as "$\text{iff }\Big( (a, b \mid t)\text{ and }(a, b \mid c \to t \mid c)\Big)$". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: My book says $t$ is lcm of $a, b$ iff $2$ different assumptions hold: $a, b$ divide $t$ and if $a, b$ divide $c$, then $t$ divides $c$.

Comment: Does the book say that that's the DEFINITION, or does the book say that's something you're supposed to _prove_? Your question seems to be asking how to _prove_ that.  If that's something you want to _prove_, then you must be taking something else to be the definition. I assumed that it was that $t\le\text{ all other common multiples}$. If the book takes that to be the _definition_, then your question becomes completely unclear. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Definition: lcm of nonzero integers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ is the smallest positive integer $m$ s.t. $a_i$ divides $m$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$ and is denoted $[1, 2, \ldots, k]$.

Comment: If that is the definition you're using then the answer I posted below answers the question. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote "iff $a, b \mid t$ and $a, b \mid c \to t \mid c$".  I think this was to be parsed as

"$\text{iff }\Big( \Big(a, b \mid t\text{ and }a, b \mid c\Big) \to t \mid c\Big)$",

not as

"$\text{iff }\Big( (a, b \mid t)\text{ and }(a, b \mid c \to t \mid c)\Big)$".

You have $a,b\mid t$ by definition and $a,b\mid c$ by hypothesis.  Is $\gcd(t,c)$ equal to $t$ or less than $t$?  Do you know that $\gcd(t,c) = at+bc$ for some integers $a,b$? If not, then maybe that part is most of the work you'll need to do. Can you use that to to show that $a,b\mid \gcd(t,c)$?  If $a,b\mid \gcd(t,c)$ and $t$ is the **smallest** number that $a,b$ both divide, then $\gcd(t,c)$ cannot be smaller than $t$, so it must be equal to $t$.  Since $\gcd(t,x)\mid c$, we then get $t\mid c$.

Comment: @ Michael Hardy, I thought I understood the proof at the time you wrote this post, but I am not so sure now.  $a \mid t, c \to a \mid (tx + cy) \text { and } b \mid t, c → b | (tx + cy)$. Then $a, b \mid (t, c)$. That's to answer your question. What I forgot to ask is if we start with $lcm(a, b) = t$, does the proof look identical to that in your post?